My header nav only opens the mobile menu after refreshing the whole website on some browsers like Chrome
I have a hamburger nav that is supposed to open a mobile menu when clicked. On some browsers it works, on others (like Chrome and Firefox) it only works after hitting refresh for the page. I used the same code before and it always worked perfectly, the only change I made is making the header stick to the top of the screen when scrolling.
Here's my code:
HTML:
<header class="grid-spaceAround" id="#top">
    <div class="col-5-middle center hide-md margin-b-2">
        <a href="/index"> 
            <div class="relative logo">
                <img src="/uploads/LOGO.jpg" alt="logo">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <nav class="col-12-middle center hide-md">
        <a href="/index"> Start </a>
        <a href="/profil"> Profil </a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="/index#leistungen" class="dropdown-title"> Leistungen </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/insolvenz"> Insolvenz </a>
                <a href="/strafrecht"> Strafrecht </a>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <a href="/honorar"> Honorar </a>
        <a href="/index#anfahrt"> Anfahrt </a>
        <a href="/index#kontakt"> Kontakt </a>
        <a href="/formulare"> Formulare </a>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-9-middle left show-md tall-5">
        <a href="/index"> 
            <div class="relative logo">
              <img src="/uploads/LOGO.jpg" alt="logo">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>  
        
    <div class="col-3-middle right show-md">
      <a class="hamburger-button"> </a>
    </div>
    
<div class="mobile-menu center"> 
    <nav class="padded-t-10 center"> 
        <a href="/index"> Start </a>
        <a href="/profil"> Profil </a>
        <dl class="accordion">
            <dt> <a href="/index#leistungen"> Leistungen </a> </dt>
            <dd>
                <a href="/index#leistungen"> Alle Leistungen </a>
                <a href="/insolvenz"> Insolvenz </a>
                <a href="/strafrecht"> Strafrecht </a> 
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <a href="/honorar"> Honorar </a>
        <a href="/index#anfahrt"> Anfahrt </a>
        <a href="/index#kontakt"> Kontakt </a>
        <a href="/formulare"> Formulare </a>
    </nav>
</div> 

</header>

JavaScript:
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hamburger Button
  $('.hamburger-button').click(function(){
      $('.mobile-menu').fadeToggle(100);
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});

CSS:
header {
    padding: 1rem 5%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: var(--accent); 
    color: var(--light);
}

header a:hover {
  color: var(--light);
}

nav a {
    padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
    margin: 0 0.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: var(--dark);
}

header nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav a:hover {
  color: var(--dark);
}


.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 7%; 
} 



/* ------------ Hamburger ----------*/

.hamburger-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5%;
    top: 0rem;
    z-index: 6;
}
  
/* Styles when the hamburger button is active  */
.hamburger-button::before {
    content: "☰";
    color: var(--light);
}
 
.hamburger-button.active::before {
   content: "✕";
   color: var(--light);
}
  
  
.mobile-menu {
    display: none; 
    background-color: var(--dark);
    color: var(--light);
    padding: 15%;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index:3;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
  
.mobile-menu a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: inherit; 
    padding: 5%;
    border: 1px solid var(--light);
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0.7rem;
}

.mobile-menu a:hover {
    color: var(--accent);
    border: 1px solid var(--accent);
}

I already tried setting the z-index of the hamburger to a higher number, that didn't work.
I put the JavaScript code snippet inside this command but it didn't help either.
$(document).ready(function() {}); 

I'm just confused because technically the code is working, I just don't understand why I have to refresh the page in some browsers before it works.
I also double checked that I added jQuery correctly, that's not the issue.
